# Dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 installation with Windows 11

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-11

I have a new laptop (Dell XPS 15 9530) that came with Windows 11. The official data sheet does not list Ubuntu as supported operating system, but an online search showed that a dual boot setup with Ubuntu should work.

I tried to follow the following resource https://www.xda-developers.com/dual-boot-windows-11-linux/.
I downloaded the Ubuntu 20.04 ISO and created a bootable USB drive using Rufus. I created a large enough disk partition (all as described in the resource). I reboot from the USB drive and run the Ubuntu installer, but I never arrive at the screen they show on their website which allows to mark *Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager*.

Instead I see this:

[image]:

There is nothing else in the drop-down menu, and simply clicking on *Install now* gives `No root file system is defined`.

Comment: New system, need new distribution to include latest kernels & drivers to support that new hardware. You need at least 22.04 LTS which now is at .3 and upgraded kernel. You may need 23.04 or even the not yet released 23.10 (you then are testing it, not supported here).  My Dell 5310 with 11th Gen Intel just worked with 22.04. I did have to turn off Windows fast startup & bitlocker. And have updated UEFI and SSD firmware. Usually Windows updates firmware, it you still  have it. Be sure to install optional restricted drivers to get nVidia driver installed.

Comment: 23.04 worked, thank you very much!

Comment: Note that it has a limited support cycle &  you will have to upgrade, or reinstall. Ubuntu 23.04 ‘Lunar Lobster’ ends in January of 2024 and next LTS - long term support will not be out until 24.04, April. I prefer to use LTS versions and totally reinstall every 2 years. I keep two / (root) partitions & alternate, so old install it still there for a while.